# Why eclipse doesn't recognize some javadocs tags?

Tags: java, eclipse

I create a class `A` that inherit from onother class `B`,

I try to inherit also the javadoc of the class B to the class `A`.

So I use the folowing tag:

```
/***
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * @author 
 *
 */
```

But eclipse doesn't recognize this tag when I press `CTRL`+`SPACE`, and there is no doc displayed for the class `A`.

Any body has any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid in a class comment. You can only use it in method comments.

The Oracle Javadoc [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDochttps://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#@inheritDoc) on {@inheritDoc} says:

> This tag is valid only in these places in a doc comment:
>
> - In the main description block of a method. In this case, the main description is copied from a class or interface up the hierarchy.
> - In the text arguments of the @return, @param and @throws tags of a method. In this case, the tag text is copied from the corresponding
>     tag up the hierarchy.

Comment: @Yacine There is good reason for this:  Two classes should never have the same class-level javadoc.  Why have two different classes in the first place if they are identical in function and purpose?  Methods, on the other hand, may be multiple implementations of the same contract, so inheritDoc makes sense there.